# How to disable a set of input methods (languages) on win 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language, input-languages

I use different app in different language (English and Hungarian) So I enabled English and Hungarian input languages, and keyboard-layouts. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> can change between these input styles.

But I don't want to use the English input language with Hungarian keyboard. (The selected in the image below.)

[image]

**I want to disable this option permanently.** How can it be done?

I want to use the same keyboard layout than the input language.
(I don't know what the aim of using different layout than the input language.)

(My problem is that sometime windows switches to this unwanted option ((because windows)) and I type several unwanted character (because of the wrong layout) and I despairingly switching between input languages and keyboards pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> several times which is extremely annoying.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution:

`Go Settings -> Time & language -> Region & language`

Click on an language from the list at the bottom of the window. Click `Options` then add or remove Keyboards.